# Why NodeJS heap space statistics are not accurate?

Tags: node.js, v8

While debugging a nodejs memory issue I noticed that NodeJS heap space statistics are never accurate, **while looking into single space** but these are accurate **while summing up total.**

```
v8.getHeapSpaceStatistics()
spaces = [ { space_name: 'new_space',
    space_size: 1048576,
    space_used_size: 462400,
    space_available_size: 569280,
    physical_space_size: 1048576 },
  { space_name: 'old_space',
    space_size: 4149248,
    space_used_size: 3535424,
    space_available_size: 297952,
    physical_space_size: 4149248 },
  { space_name: 'code_space',
    space_size: 3145728,
    space_used_size: 1284352,
    space_available_size: 128,
    physical_space_size: 3145728 },
  { space_name: 'map_space',
    space_size: 1126400,
    space_used_size: 258984,
    space_available_size: 0,
    physical_space_size: 1126400 },
  { space_name: 'large_object_space',
    space_size: 0,
    space_used_size: 0,
    space_available_size: 1487879680,
    physical_space_size: 0 } ]
```

If we match numbers for single space `space_available_size + space_used_size`, its never equal to `space_size`.

But if we sum up `space_size` for all spaces and check it against `v8.getHeapStatistics().total_heap_size` that result accurate match.

Does anyone have an idea why single space numbers never match?